# Cross domain ajax request headers on different servers

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

When I try to send cross domain request to google.docs url it works, but when i try to send it to server on another domain, it gives error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://katrin.kit.edu/adei/services/getdata.php?db_server=orca&db_name=orca_process&db_group=Data_001_PAC_dat&db_mask=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7&window=-1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But when i try google.doc it return normal parsed object without any error.

My request:

```
 function ajax(url, callback, filetype, type) {
filetype = filetype ? filetype : 'json';
type = type ? type : 'GET';
var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
var success = function(e) {
    var items = '';
    switch(filetype) {
        case 'csv': items = csv(xhr.responseText); break;
        case 'json': items = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); break;
        default: items = xhr.responseText; break;
    }
    callback(items);
}
var error = function(e) { console.log('Please enabled CORS using  access-control-allow-origin'); }
if (window.XDomainRequest && !sameOrigin(url)) { xhr = new XDomainRequest(); xhr.onload = success; }
if (filetype == 'image' && xhr.overrideMimeType) { xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'); }
xhr.onerror = error;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) { if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { success(e); } }
try {
    if ('withCredentials' in xhr) { xhr.open(type, url, true); }
    else { xhr.open(type, url); }
    xhr.send(null);
}
catch(e) { error(e); }
}

// check if url is same domain

function sameOrigin(url){
   var split = url.split('/');
   if (split[0]+'//' == window.location.protocol+'//') { return split[2] != window.location.host ? false : true; }
   else { return true; }
}

// calculate length of object

function size(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
 return size;
}
```

I tried to change headers, but there is still issues:

Here is headers for myserver url:
[image: myanotherserverurl]

Here is headers for google doc url:
[image]

Secondly I've tried to setup myserver-localhost. Added some headers to response like:

```
def index(request):
data = {
    'title': getattr(settings, 'TITLE'),
    'description': getattr(settings, 'DESCRIPTION')
}
response = render_to_response('dimension/index.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'  
response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'  
response['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1000'  
response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'  
return response
```

But i think the problem is not related with my localhost server.

And I tried jsonp library. It works, but actually with only json files. But i need different formats like csv.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't see the images. Please, post the text instead of images. By the way, it is possible to get csv files ('text') with jsonp requests. In fact, it's extremely easy with jQuery.

Comment: @OscarPaz, Can you write here, how to use jsonp to parse any data type. Because I googled so many sites and found out that it's impossible ( I mean it's possible if csv file place into 1 json object like : { obj1 : 'csv'}

Answer (score 2):

To make cross domain request, the domain that you are requesting to should give you permission and that permission is sent back in header to the browser as the response to the request. If the browser finds that your name is not in list of allowed clients, the browser will show you error. So, you just can't make a request at any domain. This is to prevent CSRF- Cross Site Request Forgery.